# Get monthly reports on SQl even if null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get monthly report of my table using this query

```
select
    month(date_reception),
    count(mc_object)
from
    [full]
where
    date_reception > '2015-01-01'
    and date_reception < '2015-06-26'
    and mc_object LIKE '%obj1%'
group by
    (month(date_reception))
```

It works fine but it only gives me results when rows of certain month is different from 0, i need to get all results event if it number of objects is 0.

Comment: do you mean even for month, where no data exist in the table?
E.g. there are no entries in march but wount a row like `3     0`?

Comment: Post some sample data. I assume that you are expecting one row for each month, with a value of zero for those months that do not have any matching data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
   select
        month(date_reception),
        count(mc_object)
    from
        [full]
    where
        date_reception > '2015-01-01'
        and date_reception < '2015-06-26'
        and (mc_object LIKE '%obj1%' OR mc_object is null) 
    group by
        (month(date_reception))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have data for all months -- just not for the particular object -- then the easiest way is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select month(date_reception) ,
       sum(case when mc_object LIKE '%obj1%' then mc_object else 0 end)
from [full]
where date_reception > '2015-01-01' and
      date_reception < '2015-06-26'    
group by month(date_reception)
```

(Note you should include the year as well.)

If this assumption is not true, then you need a list of dates and a `left join`.  There are multiple ways you can generate this:

- You might have a table of dates.
- You can use a recursive CTE to generate the dates.
- You can list the dates explicitly.

The query then looks something like:

```
select month(d.date) ,
       sum(case when mc_object LIKE '%obj1%' then mc_object else 0 end)
from dates d left join
     [full] f
     on d.date = f.date_reception
where d.date > '2015-01-01' and
      d.date < '2015-06-26'    
group by month(d.date)
```